# Android - What is the best practice for background tasks?

Tags: java, android, background

my app lets user create scheduled task.

Example: Tomorow show this notification => this notification leads to this activity etc.

What is the best practice to do this? Do I need to use some background task manager? How can I do this so it will work even when App is not running?

Facebook is doing something similar, when it is not running it still checks web for useful info for you.

Can somebody point me to some tutorial or get me some example? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several solutions that are recommended by Android framework team

- [Firebase JobDispatcher](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android)
- [GCM Network Manager](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/network-manager), [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-network-manager/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0)
- [Job Scheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html) api 21+

Answer (score 0):

For showing a notification at a known point in the future (either a specific time or X hours from now) use AlarmManager to set an alarm.

For getting notifications from a server, generally you'd use push messages from the server.  Although polling the server on an alarm would also work.